# How should I manage a .st domain?

Tags: domain

I bought a .st domain. The website for these domains is awful and really confusing. I got the domain pointing to my server, but if I set up email forwarding it blows away all of my DNS information.

I can't transfer a .st domain to a standard hosting service (like godaddy or mediatemple). Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

What TLD your domain has doesn't make it any more confusing to manage. .st domains are managed just like any other:

1. At your registrar, set your DNS servers as the authoritative servers for your domain.
2. In your DNS servers, create A/CNAME/MX/etc. records as you see fit.
3. Set up apache vhosts on your server (or shared webhost) for the domains that are pointed at the server.
4. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like they have a crappy administration panel, try avoiding letting their panel do the config for you.

Look for an Advanced DNS option, or something of that nature.